# How to update PGP key on key servers?

Tags: gnupg, keyserver

The email address that I used in my PGP key has changed.

What should I do to update the key with my new email address (apart from uploading second key)?

Comment: Refer [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146309)

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple UIDs containing multiple e-mail addresses to an OpenPGP key. To do so, run (or use a graphical user interface of your choice, procedures should be similar):

- **Edit your own key**

  ```
  gpg --edit-key [your-key-id]
  ```
- **Add a user ID**

  ```
  adduid
  ```

  Now GnuPG runs some kind of assistent asking you what to include.
- **Save your key**

  ```
  save
  exit
  ```
- **Upload the modified key to the key servers**

  ```
  gpg --send-keys [your-key-id]
  ```

After uploading a key, it will take some minutes/hours until it is gossiped to all key servers. Remember that signatures are per-UID, you might want to ask your friends to resign your key if they signed your first UID. Revoking an old UID would also remove all incoming signatures to that UID.

Comment: so I can also edit this key in the Seahorse GUI and just resend it?

Comment: Yes, that works totally fine.